# 3 calendars views

Tags: views, datetime

I'm just starting to learn Views and there is quite a lot for me to study, so I have to ask you. I am working on D7.7.x, using Calendar and Views modules.

What I want to create is this: I have an event that will be happening in 3 different cites during the period of one month but during different dates. Each city has a list of events generated as separate nodes for different days. I need only one month and it should be shown permanently - even during the month of August I should see the month of December with particular days linking to agendas. And there are 3 such calendars with the same month but different days active - the user can switch the city and the calendar will change.

What would be the easiest way to do this? Maybe even not with Calendar module?

Comment: Thanks for the accept.  Found a new site that has almost all Drupal tutorials on it.  Tutr.tv  It has nodeone.se on it and a lot of DrupalCon videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To learn more about Views check out these tutorials http://nodeone.se/blogg/learn-views-screencast-series-summed-up.

If you just have a new content type (Event) (that has a date field) you can Filter Criteria by Content: Type (= Event), and Sort Criteria by Event Date Descending.  You can add a Display of Type Block, Pane, etc to suit your needs then.  The calendar is possible, but I would advise you to get just a basic view working before trying to integrate the Calendar Mod with it.

There are numerous different options that are available and the best thing would be to watch the tutorials.  Each lesson is ~10 minutes long, but cover one thing really well.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements can be met using Views itself. Views is one of the most powerful parts of Drupal and once mastered so much can be achieved. So time spent here is very worthy indeed.

Comment: Maybe you could give a hint from where to start? Or maybe there is some kind of Views screencast regarding this particular issue? Just to get on track, as views module is so complex to me at this moment ...

Comment: This site has a good resource of videos http://drupalize.me/ as well as the popular http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast.

Comment: There is also http://www.lynda.com/ all of which I have used in the past to accelerate knowledge of Drupal.